# java import "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, import

I'm about porting a linux tool to windows. The tool works fine on linux system, but now on windows I get this "cannot find symbol" error.

I have this little main class:

```
package foo;

import foo.bar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        bar.getInstance();
    }
}
```

and the error appears now, while doing javac Main.java:

import foo.bar: cannot find symbol
        ^
symbol: class bar
location: package foo

Main.java and bar.java are in the same directory.
what am I missing?

Comment: try javac *.java do you get the same result?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For one thing, `bar` should be called `Bar` to be idiomatic...

Ideally, you should compile from the directory *above* Main.java, like this:

```
javac -d out foo/Main.java foo/Bar.java
```

That will create a directory called "out" containing another directory "foo", which will contain Main.class and Bar.class. So from the parent directory again, you could run:

```
java -cp out foo.Main
```

The source locations don't *have* to match the package structure. You *could* just call javac from the directory containing `Main.java` and `Bar.java` like this:

```
javac -cp out Main.java Bar.java
```

(And then run it in the same way as before) However, it's generally a much better idea to structure your source code according to packages.

You may well find it easier to use an IDE (Eclipse or NetBeans, for example) which will handle all the compilation etc for you. If you *do* want to build a real project from the command line, you should probably look into using a full build system such as Ant or Maven.

(Note that you'd get the same error on Linux as on Windows, if you tried to compile in the same way.)

Answer (score 4):

If any of you have worked on a kotlin project and then **working on a complete Java project without the support of kotlin** in gradle, and you put a class in kotlin into the Java project and try to import that Kotlin class, you will get this import issue. Not with reference to the exact question, but someone may find it helpful.

Example : trying to import SomeClass.kt in MainActivity.java will throw this error.

Solution : Android Studio Tools Menu -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin in Project.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to compile properly the class bar before attempting to compile foo, this is, generate the class file in the proper package structure.