# Android JDK 7 wildcard imports

Tags: java, android, cordova, java-7

I am experimenting with developing Phonegap plugins for Android using the Phonegap CLI and JDK 7.  Time and time again I have found that wildcard imports do not work and I have to explicitly import each class that I need to use.  A case in point.  I am currently playing with using Rhino to run JS without a WebView.  The code samples I find out there suggest `import org.mozilla.javascript.*` which starts throwing up compiler errors as soon as I put in code that uses the Rhino `Context` etc objects.  In order to be able compile correctly I need to do a whole series of explicit imports.  e.g.

```
import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;
import org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Function;
import org.mozilla.javascript.NativeObject;
```

Without such imports I end up with error messages along the lines of

```
cannot find symbol

NativeObject result = (NativeObject)     
function.call(rhino,scope,scope,functionParams);  
symbol:   class NativeObject
```

Is this a constraint imposed by Phonegap or something that got introduced with JDK 7 (I assume that most of the sample code I am depending on predates JDK 7) or something else altogether.  I can see how the Context object in Android can create a conflict here but I am equally certain that I am not accidentally using other classes that define Scriptable, ScriptableObject etc.

I'd be most grateful to anyone who might be able to clarify.

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: maybe there are naming conflicts so you have to explicite define which namespaces you want to use.

Comment: see my edit - I show a typical error message

Comment: This seems for me to be this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339637/java-import-cannot-find-symbol

Comment: Do you have any own implemented `NativeObject`?

Comment: Just edited my question - I am positive I do not have another implementation of NativeObject anywhere