# Cannot Find Symbol even though they are in the same package

Tags: java

Here is the link to my project: https://github.com/Knightbomb8/Infix-prefix-postfix-

Anytime I try to run and compile the code, it always errors out and says it cannot find symbols. The symbols that it cannot find are references to other classes in the same package. I am confused to why I am getting this issue. Thank you. Here is a picture of the issue: [The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5ajk.png)

> C:\Users\donal\OneDrive\Documents\School-Pamona\CS 2400 Data
>   Structures\Project1>java InfixToPrefixAndPostfix/main.java
>   InfixToPrefixAndPostfix\main.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
>           ArrayStack operand_stack = new ArrayStack<>();
>           ^   symbol:   class ArrayStack   location: class Main InfixToPrefixAndPostfix\main.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
>           ArrayStack operand_stack = new ArrayStack<>();
>                                                     ^   symbol:   class ArrayStack   location: class Main
>   InfixToPrefixAndPostfix\main.java:218: error: cannot find symbol
>           ArrayStack open_delimiter_stack = new ArrayStack<>();
>           ^   symbol:   class ArrayStack   location: class Main InfixToPrefixAndPostfix\main.java:218: error: cannot find symbol
>           ArrayStack open_delimiter_stack = new ArrayStack<>();
>                                                            ^   symbol:   class ArrayStack   location: class Main 4 errors error: compilation
>   failed

If the picture is not working, that is the exact error I got

Comment: What is the exact error message, including the symbol it can't find and the file/line reference generating the error?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I posted a screenshot at the very end showing the error. Are you not able to see the picture?

Comment: I believe you should post here what exactly are you trying to do: You say "I try to run and compile the code" - how exactly it's done, what command do you run, from which folder? All-in-all I believe you misuse the javac command.

Comment: @MarkBramnik I am compiling the code by running javac *.java and it compiles perfectly. I compile inside the infixtoprefixandpostfix folder.  After compiling, I attempt to run the entire package with java infixtoprefixandpostfix/main.java and it gives me this error. I run the command from the folder that contains the infixtoprefixandpostfix folder.  Does it sounds like I am doing something wrong? I am still pretty new to java.

Comment: I'd look at how your classpath is meant to be set in the environment where you're building

Comment: Okay I will look into that. I did just notice that when I compile i get some weird files created : Main$InvalidExpression.class and LinkedListStack$Node.class

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now its clear :)

There are some mistakes indeed:

First of all when you use packages and define `package abc` don't fiddle with Upper case in the name of the folder. Some operating systems are case sensitive so it can be problematic.
In your case rename the folder to `infixtoprefixandpostfix`.

Now, regarding the compilation:

I've successfully compiled your project with the following command: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac infixtoprefixandpostfix/*.java`

Of course, you can use just `javac` instead of `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac` if it's added to Path.

After that I run with:

`%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java infixtoprefixandpostfix.Main`

Comment: for reference adding:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339637/java-import-cannot-find-symbol

Comment: Thank you so much. I was unaware of that issue